# React : Fetching data from inputs using createRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was trying to fetch data from an input form.

The object that is being outputted is null instead of it being the input data.

I was expecting the object to have the input form data and log the same on console however it is a null object

```js
import React from 'react';
import { getFunName } from '../helpers';



class StorePicker extends React.Component  {

  //myInput = React.createRef();
constructor(){
  super();
  this.myInput = React.createRef();
  this.goToStore = this.goToStore.bind(this);
}
  goToStore = event => {
    //stop the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    //fetch the page input of the page
    console.log(this.myInput);
  }
  render() {
    return  (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form className="store-selector" onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
          <h2>Enter a store name.</h2>
          <input
            type="text"
            required placeholder="Store Name"
            defaultValue={getFunName()}
            ></input>
          <button type="submit"> Visit the Store </button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

  }
}

export default StorePicker;
```

Comment: Hi @Srinabh, please see my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to assign the `ref` to the input tag.

```
<input
  ref={this.myInput}
  type="text"
  required placeholder="Store Name"
  defaultValue={getFunName()}
></input>
```

Then in your event-handler, reach into the `ref` to extract the value.

```
  goToStore = event => {
    //stop the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    //fetch the page input of the page
    if(this.myInput.current){
       console.log(this.myInput.current.value)
    }
  }
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-murdock-30rbu